# How to get rid of "Unsafe statement written to the binary log" message

Tags: mysql

I am executing a simple UPDATE statement to update a field in Contact table based on record with specified ID in HTMLEmailLog table. Here is the query:

```
UPDATE Contact AS c 
INNER JOIN HTMLEmailLog AS h ON c.CustomerID = h.MemberID and c.Email1 = h.Email        
    SET c.ValidEmail1 = 'N'
WHERE h.id = 160605 ;
```

And I get a warning:

*Warning from last query: 
Note: Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format 
since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an 
auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because 
the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be
written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the 
slave*

Can someone please explain why do I get this warning message?
Any way to get rid of this warning?
If I UPDATE the Contact table directly (without using JOIN), I don't get the warning message.

Thanks.

Comment: This is just a warning, not an error message.

Comment: I understand that this is just a warning, however, I don't understand why do I get this warning as no ORDER is involved and no new records are bring inserted, just updating a character field. Perhaps, it is something to do with a timestamp field I have in the Contact table.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not an error message, this is a warning. It means that mysql has concerns whether the update statement can be replicated accurately to the slaves using statement based replication.

1. If you do not use replication, then this is not of any concern.
2. If you use replication, then consider changing the [replication mode to mixed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-formats.html). In mixed mode mysql will use row based replication instead of statement based if a potentially unsafe statement is detected.

You may also try to rewrite the update to use a subquery instead of a join to indicate that only the `contact` table is to be updated:

```
UPDATE Contact AS c         
SET c.ValidEmail1 = 'N'
WHERE (c.CustomerID, c.Email1) IN (SELECT MemberID, Email FROM HTMLEmailLog WHERE id = 160605);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The UPDATE query using subquery also displays the same warning.

Comment: In this case you need to use the mixed mode replication if you want to get rid of the warning.